# SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am new to rails and trying to run a `bundle exec rake db:setup`
command but am getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/ahmed/stories/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ahmed/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/ahmed/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: share some more code, what changes have you done. Impossible to guess anything like this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solve it?

Comment: i was having this problem because of elasticsearch i reinstalled it and now it's solved @AboozarRajabi